# Legality of doing private or scholastic virology with human pathogens?

Tags: virology

Is it ok for a student, say a graduate student in biochemistry, to do amateur virology using potential human pathogens?

For example, lets say the student gets a cold and tries to isolate the virus causing the cold. Is it ok for the student to do that in a school lab? How about a home lab?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it pertains to law, not biology.

Comment: @canadianer Virology is part of biology.

Comment: Law isn’t though…

Comment: If you ask a question about the law, you need to state where you live. Alternatively, if you are in gaol, as your name implies, different rules will apply.

Comment: @canadianer This is not just about law, but safety as well, so I think it is better not to close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** I think that doing this unofficially, at home, might be no big deal, but doing it in an institutionally supported lab (or any kind of institutional setting, e.g. if you wanted to publish a paper from the results) could involve lots of hassle and red tape.

I'm not a microbiologist, but ... technically I think this would fall under the category of BSL-2 - via [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biosafety_level#Biosafety_level_2):

> Biosafety level 2 is suitable for work involving agents of moderate potential hazard to personnel and the environment.[9] This includes various microbes that cause mild disease to humans, or are difficult to contract via aerosol in a lab setting.[11] Examples include Hepatitis A, B, and C viruses, human immunodeficiency virus (HIV), pathogenic *Escherichia coli*, *Staphylococcus aureus*, *Salmonella*, *Plasmodium falciparum*, and *Toxoplasma gondii*.

BSL-2 requires (among others) access control for labs; special safety training for all lab personnel; use of containment equipment for procedures that may cause infectious aerosols or splashes ...

It may seem a little crazy to lump a common-cold-causing rhinovirus with HIV, but BSL-1 (the mildest level of infectious agent control) is restricted to

> well-characterized agents **which do not cause disease in healthy humans**

(emphasis added). Note that even BSL-1 requires lab safety protocols beyond those for non-infectious agents.

A bit more internet searching on BSL classification for rhinoviruses (the typical cause of the common cold) suggests some variation: e.g.

- [Google search for "rhinovirus BSL"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=rhinovirus+bsl) brings up a bunch of hits from the American Type Culture Collection (ATCC) for a variety of rhinovirus isolates that range from BSL-1 to BSL-2
- the [Public Health Agency of Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/public-health/services/laboratory-biosafety-biosecurity/pathogen-safety-data-sheets-risk-assessment/rhinovirus.html) classes rhinoviruses as BSL-2

Comment: Depends on. S/he already got that infection so it is not a big risk to get it again... BSL1 is ok I think.

Comment: It wouldn't be your/their decision, it would be the institutional biosafety office's decision. And it's not whether it causes disease in *that particular person* (e.g. even if you vaccinated everyone in the lab against a pathogen, you'd still have to obey BSL-2 protocols). (I agree that this set of experiments would be 99.999% safe, but the rules are still there.)

Comment: I agree that you have to obey BSL protocols if you are working with pathogens, but I think applying BSL-2 for a common cold virus would be a huge exaggeration. I guess the school lab has a supervisor, so s/he should ask that person whether working with common cold virus is allowed and if so which protocol should they follow.